# What tool visually maps out existing websites?

Tags: web, sitemap

I used a tool a few months ago that scanned a specified website and created a visual hierarchy of the website's page links.  It also represented each page with its appropriate screenshot.

Does anyone know what tool this is?  Or maybe something that performs the same basic features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Scratch that, I found it**!  [InfoRapid's Knowledge](http://www.inforapid.de/html/knowledgemapeng.htm)
It produces visual sitemaps like this one of Google:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

- Visio
- Front page

there is also a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318563/generating-a-visual-site-map-of-an-existing-site)